# How can I get input fields to validate onkeyup?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that validates using ajax. When the button is submitted the input fields highlight if they are not valid, and an alert box comes up. If the form is submitted again and data in the input fields is valid, the input box is not highlighted.

Right now, I can't seem to get the input fields to validate onkeyup, cut past etc.

I would like the `<p>` tags within the if statement to validate on onkeyup, and input fields to validate onkeyup. Right now, I can only make that happen when the submit button is clicked.

What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/b6eudmuf/4/

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
$('form #response2').hide();


$('.button2').click(function(e) {
$('input[type="text"]').on("keyup bind cut copy paste", function(){
});

e.preventDefault();

var valid = '';
var required = ' is required';
var first = $('form #first').val();
var last = $('form #last').val();
var email = $('form #email').val();
var tempt = $('form #tempt').val();
var tempt2 = $('form #tempt2').val();


if(first=='' || first.length<=1) {
if (/^\s*$/.test(first.value));
    $('form #first').css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
    $('form #first').css('background-color','#ffcece');
    valid += '<p>Your first name is required</p>';
}
else {
    $('form #first').css('border','1px solid #ffd09d');
    $('form #first').css('background-color','#ffffff');
}

if(last=='' || last.length<=1) {
    $('form #last').css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
    $('form #last').css('background-color','#ffcece');
    valid += '<p>Your last name' + required + '</p>';
}
else {
    $('form #last').css('border','1px solid #ffd09d');
    $('form #last').css('background-color','#ffffff');
}

if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
    valid += '<p>Your e-mail address' + required + '</p>';
}

if (tempt != 'http://') {
    valid += '<p>We can\'t allow spam bots.</p>';
}

if (tempt2 != '') {
    valid += '<p>A human user' + required + '</p>';
}

if (valid != '') {
    $('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('error2')
        .html('' +valid).fadeIn('fast');
}

else {
    $('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('processing2').html('<p style="top:0px; left:0px; text-align:center; line-height:1.5em;">Please wait while we process your information...</p>').fadeIn('fast');

    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    submitFormSubscribe(formData);
}

});

});

function submitFormSubscribe(formData) {

$.ajax({

type: 'POST',
url: 'http://3elementsreview.com/blog/wp-content/themes/3elements/php-signup/sign-up-complete.php',
data: formData,
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
timeout: 4000,
success: function(data) {

$('form #response2').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error2' : 'success2')
          .html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');

if ($('form #response2').hasClass('success2')) {
setTimeout("$('form #response2').fadeOut('fast')", 6000);
}

},
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

$('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('error2')
.html('<p>There was an <strong>' + errorThrown +
'</strong> error due to an <strong>' + textStatus +
'</strong> condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');
},
complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {                    
$('form')[0].reset();
}   
});
};
```

Comment: Your `keyup` handler function appears to be empty/blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks liks you are binding an empty keyup event handler inside the click event of elements with the 'button2' CSS class:

```
$('.button2').click(function (e) {
        $('input[type="text"]').on("keyup bind cut copy paste", function () {});
```

What you want is:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').on("keyup bind cut copy paste", function () {
        //Put your validation logic here - this is the code that will fire on each keyup
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, I would use alerts in your code.  Put an alert inside an event handler when you're not sure whether or not it's firing.

Comment: Alerts are a hassle.. I'd prefer console.log

Comment: Stan, I only get the same thing. When I click the button validation is checked, but the input fields do not change onkeyup.

Comment: You didn't do what I said.  You still have your keyup event handler inside of your 'button2' click event handler.  You need to remove the 'button2' click event handler from the equation, like I posted in my answer.